# react native throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event

Tags: react-native

```
BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 14s
28 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 27 up-to-date
Running adb -s 988ad833354d59594330 reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081
Starting the app on 988ad833354d59594330 (adb -s 988ad833354d59594330 shell am start -n com.celebrations/com.celebrations.MainActivity)...
Starting: Intent { cmp=com.celebrations/.MainActivity }
events.js:167
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: spawn cmd.exe ENOENT
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:232:19)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:407:16)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
Emitted 'error' event at:
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:238:12)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:407:16)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
```

I was building the code for the first time and getting this error while compiling.
**any solutions for this error??**

Answer (score 0):

It means you already use port 8081, but you can run these commands:

- sudo lsof -i :8081
- kill -9 < PID >